# Combine multiple rows into one row based on Column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse csv file which I have done almost but stuck at one point. **I want to combine row with the previous row Where Column 1 of the previous row should not be null** . I have data format like this.

```
C1       C2          C3       C4      C5 

1001    1S30       5:00:00    MP      GL
NaN     1M94       9:06:00    GL      MP
1101    1P1        6:35:00    MP      Vic
NaN     9E06       07:02:00   Vic     N
NaN     9M08       10:02:00   N       Liv
NaN     9E13       13:26:00  Liv      Vic
NaN     1P26       4:40:00   Vic      MP
```

**I want to combine rows like in the below given format**

[image]

I am stuck because

here any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could please paste your data directly and remove the images? Also, could you provide a more detailed explanation of what you mean by "combine row with the previous row". It seems to me that the desired output only removed the rows that starts with NaN.

Comment: @vmouffron I am sharing it

Comment: @vmouffron I want to combine the rows if the C1 Column in the  next row is null then it should be combine with the previous row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
df.groupby(df['C1'].ffill()).apply(lambda x: x.stack().reset_index())[0].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       C1     0     1        2   3    4     5         6    7   8  ...   11  \
0  1001.0  1001  1S30  5:00:00  MP   GL  1M94   9:06:00   GL  MP  ...  NaN   
1  1101.0  1101   1P1  6:35:00  MP  Vic  9E06  07:02:00  Vic   N  ...    N   

    12    13        14   15   16    17       18   19   20  
0  NaN   NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN      NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  Liv  9E13  13:26:00  Liv  Vic  1P26  4:40:00  Vic   MP  

[2 rows x 22 columns]
```

---

Try:

```
df.groupby(df['C1'].ffill()).apply(pd.melt, id_vars='C1')['value'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       C1     0     1        2        3     4        5         6         7  \
0  1001.0  1S30  1M94  5:00:00  9:06:00    MP       GL        GL        MP   
1  1101.0   1P1  9E06     9M08     9E13  1P26  6:35:00  07:02:00  10:02:00   

          8  ...   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19  
0       NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  13:26:00  ...   MP  Vic    N  Liv  Vic  Vic    N  Liv  Vic   MP  

[2 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: Its just like what I wanted but the problem is that the arrangement of column is not proper

Comment: the arrangement of column should be like the column of 1st row should print first and then column of second row